# Expression not working against EF4.1

Tags: expression, entity-framework-4.1

Is there someone who can please explain why the following  is not working??:
the model is defined like this (very simple version)

```
 public class Monument
{
        [Key]
        public int? MonumentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The Find method in my repository implementation is defined like this:

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
{
    return _dbset.Where(where);
}
```

The where parameter gets a value this way:

```
 whereClause = c => (   (FilteringRecord.MonumentId <= 0 ? 
true : c.MonumentId == FilteringRecord.MonumentId) 

&& (String.IsNullOrEmpty(FilteringRecord.Name) ? 
true :c.Name.Contains(FilteringRecord.Name))        );
```

So if the value of FilteringRecord.MonumentId is equal to a number i get the desired record, but if the FilteringRecord.Name has a value it's completely ignored!! Why???

The same works fine on the first version of Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL!!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: "...it's completely ignored": Does that mean that the query always returns no records although there are definitely records in the DB which meet the criteria defined in FilteringRecord?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the expression is working as expected! The error was caused by a wrong binding in the UI (this is a WPF application), giving wrong values to FilteringRecord!